# Download File no asp net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho arquivos que foram feitos upload na pasta wwwroot/arquivos/ do meu projeto. Quero fazer download desses arquivos mas quando clico no botão nada acontece.

```
public ActionResult DownloadFile(string arquivo)
    {

        if (arquivo == null)
            return Content("filename not present");

        var path = Path.Combine(
                       Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),
                       "wwwroot", "arquivos", arquivo);
        var memory = new MemoryStream();

        var writer = new StreamWriter(memory);
        writer.Flush();
        memory.Position = 0;
        return File(memory, GetContentType(path), arquivo);
    }
```

html

```
<li>Download:                     
   <a class="btn btn-primary mb-3" onclick="downloadMaterial(this)" name=@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Arquivo)><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></span></a>
</li>

function downloadMaterial(e){
  var path = e.name;
  var arquivo = path.split("arquivos/")[1];
    $.ajax({
      url: '@Url.Action("DownloadFile")',
      type: "POST", 
      cache: false,
      data: {'arquivo': arquivo},

    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nada acontece porque está tentando fazer o download via *Ajax*, uma outra forma de resolver isso seria abrindo uma nova janela em branco para o download, para isto basta alterar sua função *JavaScript* para o seguinte:

```
<li>Download:                     
   <a class="btn btn-primary mb-3" onclick="downloadMaterial(this)" name=@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Arquivo)><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></span></a>
</li>

<script>
    function downloadMaterial(e){
      var path = e.name;
      var arquivo = path.split("arquivos/")[1];
      window.open("/Controller/DownloadFile/?arquivo=" + arquivo, "_blank")     
    }
</script>
```

Para o download você pode fazer assim:

```
public ActionResult DownloadFile(string arquivo)
{
    if (arquivo == null)
        return Content("filename not present");

    var path = Path.Combine(
                   Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),
                   "wwwroot", "arquivos", arquivo);

    FileStream fileStream;

    try
    {
        fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(path);
    }
    catch (DirectoryNotFoundException)
    {
        return new EmptyResult();
    }

    return File(fileStream, GetContentType(path), arquivo);
}
```

Comment: Obrigada, agora está baixando. Porém o arquivo está vindo vazio...qual pode ser o erro no meu controller? Não consigo ver na minha Action o momento em que pego o arquivo, só vejo pegando o caminho do arquivo..Ou isso é feito na parte do MemoryStream?

Comment: o Path está correto?

Comment: Sim, já conferi

Comment: Outra dúvida, é net core?

Comment: Isso mesmo!....

Comment: Editei com uma alternativa

Comment: Deu certo! Obrigada